# Greasemonkey - How do you find and open aν URL on a page that starts with a specific string?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Updated

I want to open a new window for each link on a page whose URL begins with a certain string. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3763853/tonakis2108

I want it to open every link on the page that contains:

https://stackoverflow.com/users

On a new window or tab.
The url after https://stackoverflow.com/users/"string" changes after a refresh and I need to catch it.

I tried `window.open("")` typing inside `https://stackoverflow.com/users*` but no effect.

Comment: What do you mean "open every page"? Do you mean: open a new window (or tab) for every link on the current page that contains the URL fragment?

Comment: yes that's what i am looking for, the url is changing everytime I refresh so I want the script to catch that url.

Comment: What you need to do is use something like jQuery to find the link, and then pass that into `window.open`. You need to first reference jQuery in your script, in the header, first. Alternatively, you can use the built-in method of finding all nodes of type `a` and then looping over them until you find the one you want. I *greatly* prefer jQuery, though. I can try to write up an example later if no one else replies with one.

Comment: Thanks for helping me resolve this issue, I would appreciate it if you could give me an example. It's the first time I am doing something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs on the Google home page and opens all links that contain mail.google.com.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Open Some Links
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
// @namespace      http://www.yourDomainName.com/GreaseMonkey/
// @description    Opens the links to [something] when the page loads.
// @include        http*://www.google.com/
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true); //make a safe instance of jQuery

var baseUrl = "mail.google.com";

//The $ function is an alias to the jQuery function. It's shorter, and most commonly used. 
//You pass a selector string into the $ function to select some elements on the page.
//We want to find all "a" tags (anchors) whose href attribute contains the baseUrl. *= is the "atribute contains" selector. 
//See: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for other selectors.
//To make it clearer, after adding in the baseUrl, this will be $( "a[href*='mail.google.com']" )
var matchingLinks = $( "a[href*='" + baseUrl + "']" );

//Use jQuery to loop over each link and run a function for each one.
//$(this) returns a jQuery wrapper for the current node.
//This is nice because we can use jQuery functions on it, like attr, which returns the value of the specified attribute.
//If the page contains more than one link to the same href, it will be opened multiple times.
$(matchingLinks).each( 
    function(index)
    {
        window.open( $(this).attr( "href" ) );
    }
);
```

Comment: This actually worked, I couldn't get it to work with my URLs but I believe it is @include related. Thanks for the help Glazed! (Sorry for the delay).